# Eclipse - pressing space deletes the parenthesis before caret

Tags: java, eclipse

It is hard to describe so see this GIF:

[image]

When I press space to continue typing, Eclipse Java editor decides to delete the second half of a parenthesis pair. I can press ESC to prevent this, but it is annoying.

I must have missed/tweaked some settings without knowing it, because in my working station, same as in my home, I am with Eclipse Mars 2 and I had never seen this.

It also happens if I press `;` to end the line, and there is a parenthesis before the `;`.

What should I change in Preference to stop it?

Comment: I think your Eclipse might be haunted.

Comment: @Kayaman If it was haunted, it must be filled with ghosts because I just found another case where my parenthesis is eaten.... very, very hungry ghosts ;)

Comment: LISP ghosts indeed

Answer (score -1):

This is is a overtype mode in eclipse.

To disable it, press the Insert/Ins key on your keyboard and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Then it would be overtyping everything.